# form element added using javascript is not sent from post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

It may seems that this question is repeated but my question is little different and i did'nt find its answer in other questions so i am starting it as a new thread.

I have a form where there is a link on clicking which will add the html content on the div inside the form.user can add multiple times. but when i submit the form. The field added for the first time using javascript is submitted through the form but if i add multiple times then the data of second and after form is not posted through form.
I have posted my code below can anyone help me to find and solve the issue.

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('children/index/addChild') ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" autocomplete="off">

    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php //echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Child Name') ?></h2>
        <?php if(sizeof($model)==0): ?>



        <a href="javascript:show()" id="addchild">Add Child</a>

    <div id="child" style="display:none;">
        <li>
            <div class="field">
                    <label for="firstname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('First Name') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php  ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('First Name') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                    <label for="lastname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Last Name') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="<?php  ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Last Name') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
                    </div>
            </div>        
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="field">
                    <label for="schoolname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('School Name') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">

                        <select id='schoolname' name='schoolname'>
                            <option value="0">Select School</option>
                            <?php foreach ($schools as $key => $school): ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $school['school_id']; ?>"><?php echo $school['school_name'] ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach;?>


                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="field">
                    <label for="year" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Year') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="year" id="year" value="<?php  ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Year') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                    <label for="class"><?php echo $this->__('Class(if applicable)') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="class" id="class" value="<?php  ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Class') ?>" class="input-text" />
                    </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Save') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Save') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
<?php $i=1;
foreach ($model as $key => $value): ?>
    <div id="child">
        <?php 
        $arr = array(); 
        $id= $value['child_id']; 

        ?>
        <!-- <button type="button" id="removechild">Remove Child</button> -->
        <a href="javascript:remove('<?php echo $id; ?>')" id="removechild">Remove Child</a>
        <li>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="childid<?php echo $i ?>" />
            <div class="field">
                    <label for="firstname<?php echo $i ?>" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('First Name') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="firstname<?php echo $i ?>" id="firstname<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $value["firstname"]; ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__("First Name") ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                    <label for="lastname<?php echo $i ?>" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Last Name') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="lastname<?php echo $i ?>" id="lastname<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $value['lastname']; ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Last Name') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
                    </div>
            </div>        
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="field">
                    <label for="schoolname<?php echo $i ?>" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('School Name') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">

                       <select id='schoolname<?php echo $i ?>' name='schoolname<?php echo $i ?>' value='<?php echo $value['school_id'] ?>' >
                            <option value="0">Select School</option>
                            <?php foreach ($schools as $key => $school): ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $school['school_id']; ?>" <?php if($school['school_id']==$value['school_id']){echo "selected" ;} ?> ><?php echo $school['school_name'] ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach;?>


                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="field">
                    <label for="year<?php echo $i ?>" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Year') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="year<?php echo $i ?>" id="year<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $value['age']; ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Year') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                    <label for="class<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Class(if applicable)') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="class<?php echo $i ?>" id="class<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $value['class']; ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Class') ?>" class="input-text" />
                    </div>
            </div>
        </li>       

    </div>
<?php $i++; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" name="count" />
<div id="addition"></div>
<a href="javascript:duplicate(this.val)" id="anotherchild" value="1">Add Another Child</a>
<input type="hidden" id="test" value="0" name="test"/>

<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Save') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Save') ?></span></span></button>
<?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

and the script is

```
function duplicate(){


    var id=document.getElementById('test').value;

    var div = document.createElement('div');

    div.className = "row"+id;

    div.innerHTML = '<label for="firstname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__("First Name") ?></label><div class="input-box"><input type="text" name="firstname'+id+'" id="firstname'+id+'" title="<?php echo $this->__("First Name") ?>" class="input-text required-entry" /></div><label for="lastname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__("Last Name") ?></label><div class="input-box"><input type="text" name="lastname'+id+'" id="lastname'+id+'" title="<?php echo $this->__("Last Name") ?>" class="input-text required-entry" /></div><label for="schoolname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__("School Name") ?></label><div class="input-box"><select id="schoolname'+id+'" name="schoolname'+id+'"><option value="0">Select School</option><?php foreach ($schools as $key => $school): ?><option value="<?php echo $school["school_id"]; ?>" <?php if($school["school_id"]==$value["school_id"]){echo "selected" ;} ?> ><?php echo $school["school_name"] ?></option><?php endforeach;?></select></div><label for="year" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__("Year") ?></label><div class="input-box"><input type="text" name="year'+id+'" id="year'+id+'" title="<?php echo $this->__("Year") ?>" class="input-text required-entry" /></div><label for="class"><?php echo $this->__("Class(if applicable)") ?></label><div class="input-box"><input type="text" name="class'+id+'" id="class'+id+'" title="<?php echo $this->__("Class") ?>" class="input-text" /></div>';

     document.getElementById('addition').appendChild(div);
     document.getElementById('test').value= ++id;


}
```

Do not bother about the jumbled code, I just want to add the html in javascript to div named "addition".
Let me explain my scenario more clearly.There is a link to "Add another Child" when i click this link there appear the html block which is inside javascript to the div "addition".I also can add multiple child. but while submitting only one child is submitted. 
Can anyone help please.Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: is the div getting added properly?

Comment: yes i figured out what was the problem.By the way thanks for the reply

Comment: The problem was in name of the field the name of the field added by the js is same as name of the field i declared above so it replaced the value.So silly of me.But guys i appreciate for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34rYv/153/). It has submit handler which serializes your data and sends it to the server.

```
$('#form-validate').on('submit', function (e) {
    //prevent the default submithandling
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).serialize())
    //send the data of 'this' (the matched form) to yourURL
    $.post('yourSubmitUrl.php', $(this).serialize());
});
```

Comment: Hope this process will help other facing such type of problem. Thanks for the reply.